# using higher frame then dropping to lower time to find better entry and then fire alert

Tags: pine-script

Unable to get the alerts to fire. I was hoping to get some advice on the following script.

Looking for a pull back on a 4 or 1 hour time frame and drop down to a lower time frame and looking for a stochastic roll over then send an alert.

Would like it to be once per session, but this is a bridge to far for me. Just would like to see the script fire alerts than work on once per session.

Any advice appreciated.

'''

```
strategy(title="SS_Bounty", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = true)


//@version=5

strategy(title="Street_Bounce", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = true)


//inputs
var TP = "Trading Parameters"
showCrosses = input(defval=true, title="Show EMA Crosses?", group = TP)
//count = input(defval = 1, title =" How many times do you want sript to run", group =TP)
var HT = "Higher time Frame"
//var count1 = 0
emainput = input(title="EMA", defval = 50, group = HT)
ema1 =ta.ema(close, emainput)

var LT = "Lower Time Frame"
string i_Period = input.timeframe(title="Lower Timeframe", defval="30", group = LT)
periodK = input.int(12, title="%K Length", minval=1, group = LT)
smoothK = input.int(3, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1, group = LT)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1, group = LT)



///plot EMA////
plot(ema1, title ='EMA', linewidth =2, color=color.blue, display = display.pane)



///higher time frame pull back ////



longCondition = close[1] > ema1 and ta.crossunder(close, ema1) ? true : na
shortCondition = close[1] < ema1 and ta.crossover(close, ema1) ? true : na

plotarrow(showCrosses and longCondition ? 1 : 0, colorup=color.green, maxheight=50, minheight=50, display = display.pane)
plotarrow(showCrosses and shortCondition ? -1 : 0, colordown=color.red, maxheight=50, minheight=50, display = display.pane)


////lower time frame stochastic/////

MLBuy = input(title="Main Line Stoch Buy has to be below ", defval = 20, display = display.none)
MLSell = input(title="Main Line Stoch Buy has to be above ", defval =80, display = display.none)
ctf_k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
ctf_d = ta.sma(ctf_k, periodD)

[_ltf_k, _ltf_d] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, i_Period, [ctf_k, ctf_d])

len = array.size(_ltf_k)

float ltf_k = (len > 0) ? array.get(_ltf_k, len - 1) : na
float ltf_d = (len > 0) ? array.get(_ltf_d, len - 1) : na

//PLOT
//plot(ltf_k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
//plot(ltf_d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
//h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
//hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
//h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
//fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")



//Lower time frame Variables//
GetPipSize() =>
    syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1) 
SL = input.int(title = "Stop Loss in Pips", defval = 25, group = TP, display = display.none)
PIP_SL = SL * GetPipSize()
R_R = input.int(title = "Risk Reward multiplier", defval = 2, group = TP, display = display.none)
Buy_Profit = open + (PIP_SL * R_R)
Sell_Profit = open - (PIP_SL * R_R)
Buy_SL = open - PIP_SL 
Sell_SL = open + PIP_SL
var bool LTBuy = false
var bool LTSell = false
var float open1 = 0
var float open2 = 0


//NewDay = timeframe.change("1D")
 

//buy alerts
if longCondition == true  
    LTBuy := (ctf_k < MLBuy and ctf_k[2] < ctf_d[2] and ctf_k[1] > ctf_d[1]) ? true : na
    open1 := open[0]
    
   

if LTBuy == true
    alert("Buy " + syminfo.ticker + " at " + str.tostring(open1,"0.000") + "\n TP " + str.tostring(Buy_Profit,"0.000") + "\n SL " + str.tostring(Buy_SL,"0.000"), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    longCondition := false

//Sell Alerts

if shortCondition == true
    LTSell := (ctf_k > MLSell and ctf_k[2] > ctf_d[2] and ctf_k[1] < ctf_d[1]) ? true : na
    open2 := open[0]
    
    

if LTSell == true
    alert("Sell " + syminfo.ticker + " at " + str.tostring(open2,"0.000") + "\n TP " + str.tostring(Sell_Profit,"0.000") + "\n SL " + str.tostring(Sell_SL,"0.000"),alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    shortCondition := false
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You should always be on your entry timeframe. And from there, you should be looking at the higher timeframes. You are doing the opposite.

Use `request.security()` to look at the higher timeframes and make sure it does not repaint with the following method:

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Then do your anlaysis on your entry timeframe and place the order.